# WebSphere generates ClassNotFoundException when stand alone client instantiates Proxy for Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, ibm-rad

I am using `Rad 8.5` with `WebSphere 8.5.5.9` to create a simple `Web-Service` which I am trying to call with a stand alone client I generated with the `Rad` `Generate->Client` wizard.  The wizard generated the files shown in the `webservicepackage` shown below.

[image]

I am trying to call the `Web-service` with the following code.

```
package thinClientPackage;
import webservicepackage.WebServiceTestPortProxy;

public class ThinClientServiceCall {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        WebServiceTestPortProxy proxy = new WebServiceTestPortProxy();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String temp = proxy.getName("Test");
    }catch(Throwable e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

My problem is I am getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ejs.ras.hpel.HpelHelper` which is caused by a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ejs.ras.hpel.HpelHelper` when I try to instantiate the `WebServiceTestPortProxy`.  A search online said it might be solved by putting an `IBM` `thinclient` `jar` file in the runtime path which I tried but it did not help.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where did you add the lib, for websphere there are multiple ways to add the jar, you can create a shared library or put it into lib directory or server/webapp etc.... I prefer putting the lib under WEB-INF lib directory so it does not affect other applications but you may need to specify as shared library.

Comment: I copied the jar files into the Ear file which contained the Web Project.  I then used `Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add Jars` to add the jar files to the build path of the Web project. I then used `Properties->Deployment Assembly->Manifest Entries->Add` to add the jar files to the run time path.  I am running the code using `Debug As->Java Application`.  Does that not put the jars in the correct place?

Comment: Sometime you still need to add jars to server lib directory for the profile.

Comment: If you're running it as j2se (I see a main method) then the thinclient jars might need to be in the client project.  Jars from plugins directory aren't intended for a j2se environment and should not be on that project's classpath.  Probably some class from a plugins jar is referencing that hpelhelper class (a server side logging facility).  If it persists, the only thinclient jar that contains the missing class is com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0.jar

Comment: Adding com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0.jar made the problem go away.  Thanks!